# Get Location ID of Cities in android app

Tags: android, api

I write an application which use Xhanch api for getting prayer time I use [this](http://xhanch.com/xhanch-api-islamic-get-prayer-time) link for this purpose , but i don't know where can i get location id of several cities , please help me . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you looking for called geoNameId.
You could try the following API service.you have to specify the country as an ISO and recieve back info about the country include the geoNameId.

example:
http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?formatted=true&lang=en&**country=DE**&username=demo&style=full

result:

```
{
  geonames: [
    {
       continent: "EU",
       capital: "Berlin",
       languages: "de",
       geonameId: 2921044, //here is the geoNameId for Germany
       south: 47.2701236047002,
       isoAlpha3: "DEU",
       north: 54.9113475100612,
       fipsCode: "GM",
       population: "81802257",
       east: 15.0418156516163,
       isoNumeric: "276",
       areaInSqKm: "357021.0",
       countryCode: "DE",
       west: 5.86625035072566,
       countryName: "Germania",
       continentName: "Europa",
       currencyCode: "EUR"
    }
  ]
}
```

check geoNames site for more info:
http://www.geonames.org/

Comment: Thank you for you answering , but i have one another question : is this ID is same for whole cities of a country ?

Comment: For each city there is a geoNameID as well, try this link to see an example:
http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?formatted=true&north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=en&username=demo&style=full